# Sites not ordered in StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, stack-exchange-button

Usually, the sites on which you have 200 reputation are ordered from most reputation to least in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™. However, on https://chat.stackexchange.com/, they are not. It's randomized, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MultiCollider now shows the site list ordered by reputation as well.

[image]